# Python, distance between two points type issue

Tags: python, list, numpy, types

I am trying to use a simple approximation for a solution to the travelling salesman problem for 100 random points on a Cartesian grid between values of 0 - 100 on both the x and y axis using the **numpy** method.

I have created various integers that are unique and fill up three lists:

```
xList = [np.round(np.random.rand()*100)] #Generates random x,y coordinates
yList = [np.round(np.random.rand()*100)]
orderList = [np.round(np.random.rand()*100)]
```

I have defined a function that will find the shortest distance between two points on a Cartesian plane:

```
def distance(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return np.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))
```

I then iterate through this list to find the total length if a specific path travels randomly between points:

```
totalLength = 0

for i in range(0, 98):
    stuff = distance(int(xList[orderList[i]]), int(xList[orderList[i+1]]), int(yList[orderList[i]]), int(yList[orderList[i+1]]))
totalLength = totalLength + stuff

shortestLength = totalLength
```

It seems that the typing is a problem for my predefined function getting the message:

```
stuff = distance(int(xList[orderList[i]]), int(xList[orderList[i+1]]), int(yList[orderList[i]]), int(yList[orderList[i+1]]))***

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64
```

I have no idea about how to properly define types in python so I would like some advice about converting the `float.numpy64` type to an integer or allowing my predefined function to work for the correct types.

Comment: You might want to use `np.hypot` for `distance`.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.round` does not yield integers:

```
> print(type(np.round(13.4)))
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Possible solutions:

```
> int(np.round(13.4))
13 # type int
> np.int(13.4)
13 # type int
> math.trunc(13.4)
13 # type int
```

---

Consider the following reformulation of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import scipy.spatial.distance as distance

points = np.rollaxis(np.random.randn(2, 100), 1)
indices = range(points.size)

# distance.euclidean(points[5], points[10])
```

Comment: `stuff = distance(int(np.round(xList[orderList[i]])), int(np.round(xList[orderList[i+1]])), int(np.round(yList[orderList[i]])), int(np.round(yList[orderList[i+1]])))`

**_TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64_**

Comment: The problem are the elements of `orderList`. Those have to be integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `orderList` should be a numpy array (or normal Python list) of integers, not random floating-point numbers.

I assume it should be a shuffled list of numbers in the range 0 - 100. You can construct such a list in pure Python like this:

```
import random

listsize = 10
orderList = list(range(listsize))
random.shuffle(orderList)
print(orderList)
```

**typical output**

```
[6, 5, 1, 2, 0, 4, 9, 3, 7, 8]
```

(I've set `listsize` to 10 to keep the output small).

You can also pass a Numpy array to `random.shuffle`:

```
import random
import numpy as np

listsize = 10
orderList = np.arange(listsize)
random.shuffle(orderList)
print(orderList)
```

**typical output**

```
[6 9 0 1 3 7 2 5 8 4]
```

The *dtype* of the elements of this `orderList` is int32.

Actually, Numpy has its own [random.shuffle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) function, so you can replace `random.shuffle(orderList)` in the previous snippet with

```
np.random.shuffle(orderList)
```